# Select values from MapType Column in UDF PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to extract the value from the MapType column in PySpark dataframe in the UDF function.

Below is the PySpark dataframe:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|col_a       |col_b        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|    100    |{0.0 -> 1.0}| {0.2 -> 1.0}|
|    101    |{0.0 -> 1.0}| {0.2 -> 1.0}|
|    102    |{0.0 -> 1.0}| {0.2 -> 1.0}|
|    103    |{0.0 -> 1.0}| {0.2 -> 1.0}|
|    104    |{0.0 -> 1.0}| {0.2 -> 1.0}|
|    105    |{0.0 -> 1.0}| {0.2 -> 1.0}|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

```py
df.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- CUSTOMER_ID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- col_a: map (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- key: float
#  |    |-- value: float (valueContainsNull = true)
#  |-- col_b: map (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- key: float
#  |    |-- value: float (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Below is the UDF

```py
@F.udf(T.FloatType())
def test(col):
    return col[1]
```

Below is the code:

```
df_temp=df_temp.withColumn('test',test(F.col('col_a')))
```

I am not getting the value from the **col_a** column when I pass it to the UDF. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: To access MapType (dict) value, you need to access by key and your key's value is `0.0`, so I guess you need to access with `col[0.0]`.  However, you can get value of MapType with `F.col(colname).getItem(keyvalue)` without UDF.

Comment: I am getting Nulls when I use getItem()?

Comment: `F.col('col_a').getItem(0.0)`?   but looking at the answer, if you are getting some value from `F.col('col_a')[0]`, your key is probably automatically changed to integer 0 somehow (`F.col('col_a').getItem(0)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `col[1]` will successfully extract the value from *map* type column when:

- `col` is a column expression
- `1` is an existent key in the map

In your case, your map does not have a key=1, that's why it doesn't work.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(100, {0.0: 1.0},)], ['CUSTOMER_ID', 'col_a'])
df.show()
# +-----------+------------+
# |CUSTOMER_ID|       col_a|
# +-----------+------------+
# |        100|{0.0 -> 1.0}|
# +-----------+------------+

df = df.withColumn('col_a_0', F.col('col_a')[0])
df = df.withColumn('col_a_1', F.col('col_a')[1])

df.show()
# +-----------+------------+-------+-------+
# |CUSTOMER_ID|       col_a|col_a_0|col_a_1|
# +-----------+------------+-------+-------+
# |        100|{0.0 -> 1.0}|    1.0|   null|
# +-----------+------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the value using getItem?

Comment: `[0]` is not ok?

Answer (score 0):

To extract values in a maptype column use map_values()

```
df_temp.withColumn('col_a_1', array_join(map_values("col_a"),',')).show()

+-----------+------------+-------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|       col_a|col_a_1|
+-----------+------------+-------+
|        100|{0.0 -> 1.0}|    1.0|
|        101|{0.0 -> 1.0}|    1.0|
|        102|{0.0 -> 1.0}|    1.0|
+-----------+------------+-------+
```